# ASP.NET Sharing code between custom LinkButton and HyperLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, interface, webforms

I have created a custom WebControl which inherits LinkButton and has a few extra properties for changing the appearance (e.g. icons/positioning). I would like to also have an equivalent HyperLink control but it will render in exactly the same way, i.e. an <A> tag but with an href rather than causing a postback. All of the properties and rendering methods will be the same but I cannot work out how to share the code between them.

Ideally some static rendering methods would be good but LinkButton and HyperLink don't have a common ancestor other than WebControl, which is not specific enough as I need access to the CssClass and Text properties on both.

Is it even possible to create shared code that can work on both a LinkButton and HyperLink?

Comment: Off the top of my head, create adapter classes that share the same interface that wrap the properties of the LinkButton and HyperLink, or cast the objects as `dynamic` and let the DLR do the work for you (and toss intellisense and compile-time safety out the window). I feel like there must be a better way, but I haven't worked with ASP.NET for a while, so there may be better techniques. EDIT: Regarding the dynamic, best to have your styling class take a strongly typed LinkButton/HyperLink then internally use `dynamic` and add unit tests; that should help with compile time safety.